# How to output grunt target in options

Tags: node.js, dynamic, gruntjs, output, target

Given a grunt task:

```
anytask: {
    options: {
        someOption: '<%= targetName %>'
    }
    targetA: {...},
    targetB: {...}
}
```

If I ran it like this:

`grunt anytask:targetA`

I want `someOption` to have the value of `targetA` dynamically.

How can I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the only way so far I have found to do it - wrap the task in a task and dynamically set the task option..

```
grunt.registerTask('anytask-wrapper', function(target) {
    var anytask = grunt.config('anytask');

    anytask.options.someOption = target;

    grunt.config('anytask', requirejs);
    grunt.task.run(['anytask:' + target]);
});

grunt anytask-wrapper:targetB
```